# How to do Calculation in Excel Cell upon leaving the cell

Tags: excel

I work on Excel-2010 and Excel-2013. I want to do something like below:

Whatever the number I enter in cell, that number must be devided by 60 and the result should be printed on the same cell upon pressing TAB. If I come back to this cell, the entered number should be appeared, not the result of the calculation.

I don't know much about programming in Excel. I can't open most of the sites due to company security policies.

Can anyone please help me on this!

Comment: Do you have any range of cells this rule apply, or you want this rule to apply on every cell in sheet?

Comment: If the value in that cell is used in subsequent calculations, which value should be used?  The entered value, or the *divided by 60* value?

Comment: What is the purpose of this exercise?  If it is to do time calculations, there may be easier ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, it is for time calculation. The cell should be converted to 1 when I enter 60 (here I enter 60 minutes, but I should see that as 1 hour)

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: I have created one more post with my actual purpose at below location. Can you please try on that?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416787/excel-calculation-in-cell-for-certain-specified-cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code. You should paste this code in your `Worksheet module`, not `Regular module`. Then please adjust `Range("A1:A100")` to range in which numbers should be divided.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim DivRg As Range
Set DivRg = Range("A1:A100")
Set DivRg = Application.Intersect(Target, DivRg)

If DivRg Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
Target = Target / 60
Target.Offset(0, 5).Value = 1
Application.EnableEvents = True

Set DivRg = Nothing

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim DivRg As Range

Set DivRg = Range("A1:A100")
Set DivRg = Application.Intersect(Target, DivRg)

If DivRg Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Offset(0, 5).Value = 1 Then
Target = Target * 60
Target.Offset(0, 5).Value = 0
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

Set DivRg = Nothing
End Sub
```

To accomplish your task, you will need one helper column (I chose column `F`) but you can choose any column and change this part of code to address that column `Target.Offset(0, 5).Value`. For example, if you want helper column to be column `E` , then use this code `Target.Offset(0, 4).Value` . Make sure you replace this code in all 3 parts of subs.

Comment: Wouldn't this just divide whatever is entered by 60?  How does this accomplish  the rest of his request:  *If I come back to this cell, the entered number should be appeared, not the result of the calculation.*

Comment: You're right, I misinterpreted his question. I adjusted my answer. thanks for heads up.

Comment: @Kresimir L. Thank you very much for your reply, but, I am unable to use your logic for my requirement. I marked your answer as accepted one. I have created one more post at below location with more information. Can you please look into that!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416787/excel-calculation-in-cell-for-certain-specified-cells